# Why is my array sort out of order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to do the following.

First, take in a string and count the number of unique words.
Second, sort the unique word count in descending order.
Third, if two words have the same word count, then place them in order of occurrence.

Question: Why does the word "up" show up first in my returned array of arrays?

```
var doc = 
"Cause I'm Slim Shady, yes I'm the real Shady, All you other Slim Shadys are just imitating So won't the real Slim Shady, please stand up, Please stand up, Please stand up";

function wordCountEngine(doc) {
    var stringModArr = doc.replace(/[.,'\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~?()]/g, "").toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var wordLibrary = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < stringModArr.length; i++) {
        if (wordLibrary.hasOwnProperty(stringModArr[i])) {
            wordLibrary[stringModArr[i]] = String((Number(wordLibrary[stringModArr[i]])) + 1);
        } else {
            wordLibrary[stringModArr[i]] = '1';
        }
    }

    var sortable = [];
    for (var word in wordLibrary) {
        sortable.push([word, wordLibrary[word]]);
    }

    var final = sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[1] - a[1];
    });

    return final;
}

wordCountEngine(doc)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort algo used for sort function can not ensure the original order. You can debug that if you put log inside your compareFunction. Incase if the order is needed, then you have to take that into consideration while writing code. Below code might help.

var doc = 
"Cause I'm Slim Shady, yes I'm the real Shady, All you other Slim Shadys are just imitating So won't the real Slim Shady, please stand up, Please stand up, Please stand up";

```
   function wordCountEngine(doc) {
     var stringModArr = doc.replace(/[.,'\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~?()]/g, 
      "").toLowerCase().split(" ");
var wordLibrary = {};

for (let i = 0; i < stringModArr.length; i++) {
    if (wordLibrary.hasOwnProperty(stringModArr[i])) {
        wordLibrary[stringModArr[i]] = String((Number(wordLibrary[stringModArr[i]])) + 1);
    } else {
        wordLibrary[stringModArr[i]] = '1';
    }
}

var sortable = [];
let i = 0;
for (var word in wordLibrary) {
    sortable.push([i, word, wordLibrary[word]]);
    i++;
}
var final = sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(b[2] - a[2] != 0) {
      return b[2] - a[2];
    } else {
      return a[0] - b[0];
    }
});

return final.map(a => [a[1], a[2]]);
  }

  wordCountEngine(doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

"up" shows up first because your function is sorting based on the "count" descending.

```
> wordCountEngine(doc)
[ [ 'up', '3' ],
  [ 'slim', '3' ],
  [ 'shady', '3' ],
  [ 'please', '3' ],
  [ 'stand', '3' ],
  [ 'the', '2' ],
  [ 'real', '2' ],
  [ 'im', '2' ],
  [ 'you', '1' ],
  [ 'cause', '1' ],
  [ 'shadys', '1' ],
  [ 'are', '1' ],
  [ 'just', '1' ],
  [ 'imitating', '1' ],
  [ 'so', '1' ],
  [ 'wont', '1' ],
  [ 'yes', '1' ],
  [ 'all', '1' ],
  [ 'other', '1' ] ]
```

If you'd like to sort by word alphabetically use the 0 index instead of 1 when calling `sort`.

Comment: It is supposed to sort by the count. However, when two words have the same count number, it should be sorting, secondarily, by order of occurrence. so "slim", "shady", "please", "stand" are all 3 (just like "up" is 3) and are all in order. but "up" should be after "stand" (see the phrase in the doc variable).

Comment: The function you pass to `sort` needs to return an integer. Maybe you want to perform additional logic if `b[1] - a[1]` is zero?

Answer (score 1):

You push them in order, but when you sort them the order of occurrence is lost.

In order to get it back, you need to weight their count by the occurrence. This can be done by slicing to create a new array to work with, and then considering their previous order in the comparison.

```
var final = sortable.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
  var occurenceWeightA = (sortable.length - sortable.indexOf(a)) / sortable.length;
  var occurenceWeightB = (sortable.length - sortable.indexOf(b)) / sortable.length;
  return (occurenceWeightB + (+b[1])) - (occurenceWeightA + (+a[1]));
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j58zc74o/)

<sub>The use of `(+b[1])` is there in order to make sure that there is integer math instead of string concatenation. `+` is a shorthand for converting to a numeric.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach which adds to your `wordLibrary` as values to your word keys an object which keeps track of `firstIndex` and `lastIndex` the word occurred in the sentence as well as the count as before.

This allows you to better keep track and later sort and you now have the meta data to do so:

```js
var doc =
  "Cause I'm Slim Shady, yes I'm the real Shady, All you other Slim Shadys are just imitating So won't the real Slim Shady, please stand up, Please stand up, Please stand up";

function wordCountEngine(doc) {
  var stringModArr = doc.replace(/[.,'\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~?()]/g, "").toLowerCase().split(" ");
  var wordLibrary = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < stringModArr.length; i++) {
    var key = stringModArr[i],
      obj = {first: stringModArr.indexOf(key),last: stringModArr.lastIndexOf(key)}
      wordLibrary[key] = Object.assign(obj, { count: wordLibrary[key] ? Number(wordLibrary[key].count || 1) + 1 : 1 })
  }

  var sortable = [];
  for (var word in wordLibrary) {
    sortable.push([word, wordLibrary[word]]);
  }

  var final = sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1].count - a[1].count === 0 ? a[1].first - b[1].first : b[1].count - a[1].count
  });

  return final;
}

console.log(wordCountEngine(doc))
```

So the way it works is if your words have the same count you can now compare with their first occurrence etc.

You can shorten it a lot more but I wanted to keep the majority of the structure so you can feel at home :). Hope this helps.